# swift navigationAction.navigationType linkactivated does not detect relative urls

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In a WKWebView I noticed that when I tap on absolute urls the `navigationType` is `.linkActivated`, however when I tap on a relative url the `navigationType` is `.other`.

My app should display a new view every time a new link is tapped, so I had the logic to deal with that in  `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy)`.

It works fine for absolute urls, as I can check for the `.linkActivated`, but it does not work for relative urls, as I am not sure how to distinguish the tap on a relative url from others requests

Here is a sample of the code

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if self.delegate?.getCurrentViewState() != ViewState.Feed {

        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
            // apply logic to navigate to a new view
        }
        else if navigationAction.navigationType == .other {
            // somehow understand that this request is coming from relative url and apply same logic as above
        }

    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Anyone of you know if there is a way to detect if the request I am dealing with is coming from a relative url tap?

Comment: Any solution you found on this? some url the type as Other not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the solution below:

```
// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
extension NaviWebViewController {
    override func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        switch navigationAction.navigationType {
        case .linkActivated:
            linkActivated(webView: webView, navigationAction: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
        default:
            otherAction(webView: webView, navigationAction: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
        }
    }

    func linkActivated(webView: WKWebView, navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    
        guard allowLoadURL(url: url) else {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

    func otherAction(webView: WKWebView, navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let isMainFrame = navigationAction.targetFrame?.isMainFrame, isMainFrame else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
    
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    
        guard allowLoadURL(url: url) else {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

    func allowLoadURL(url: URL) -> Bool {
        let domain = GlobalConstant.domain
        if let host = url.host, host.contains(domain) {
            return true
        }
    
        return false
    }
}
```

You can read it in detail here: https://qiita.com/aryzae/items/9b3d6f77cb5082665220
I didn't find any article in English while searching